# What is an elegant solution to checking which delegate pushed the modal view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, delegates

I have a modal that displays over a `UITableViewController` which should display different text in a UITextField placeholder text depending on which `UITableViewController` called it.

One UITableViewController displays sentences, the other stories. If the modal is pushed on the `TableViewController` that displays sentences the placeholder should say "Your New Sentence"; if the modal is pushed on the TableViewController that shows Stories it should say "Your Story's Title".

I can NSLog the delegate's name on `ViewDidLoad` with:

```
NSLog(@"delegate: %@", self.delegate);
```

But I'm unsure how to check that with an if statement. 
It also feels wrong or inelegant - like it breaks design principles somewhere.

**What is an elegant solution to checking which delegate pushed the modal view controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to put a property on your custom view controller, and then set it before you present it:

```
MyModalViewController *viewController = [[MyModalViewController alloc] init];
viewController.placeholder = @"Your New Sentence";
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Then, in your view controller's viewDidLoad you can use the property value to set up the text field.

The modal view controller doesn't really need to know "who" pushed it; it just needs some information that the "who" should provide when it sets it up.

Comment: Ah. Can you hear me slapping my forehead? Good clear answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your modal controller shouldn't know anything about the delegate except that it implements whatever delegate protocol you have set up. So you have two options:

- Add a method to your delegate protocol which returns the placeholder string, your modal then asks for the string to use when it needs it.
- Make the placeholder string a property of your modal view controller and pass the placeholder string into the modal at the point of creation (in `prepareForSegue:` or when you create it or similar)

Option 1 is probably nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping a `BOOL` variable for each `controller`..in the modal...
so like this

```
BOOL view1;
BOOL view2;
BOOL view3; .. etc
```

then presenting modally set one `BOOL` to `TRUE`..depending on controller..and then in your modal `viewDidLoad` .. make a switch statement to check which value is TRUE ..and set the text